# Display a mixed list of posts and media

Tags: posts, categories, media

I have a list of articles on my website.

Some of the articles are post types with the "Article" category and others are PDF files uploaded to the media library, also with the "Article" category.
I added categories to the media library using these functions in *functions.php*:

```
// add categories for attachments
function add_categories_for_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_for_attachments' );

// add tags for attachments
function add_tags_for_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_tags_for_attachments' );
```

thanks to this [article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-media-categories-tags/).

I need to display a single category page which lists both types of posts (media and regular posts).

Is there a simple way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work :

```
$args = array ( 'post_type' => array( 'post', 'attachment'), 'category' => ARTICLE_CATID   );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me find the complete answer: $args = array('category' => $wp_query->get_queried_object_id(), 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'post_type' => array( 'post', 'attachment'),'post_status'    => array( 'publish', 'inherit'));
      $glossaryposts = get_posts( $args );

Comment: why not mark it as the answer then?

Comment: I have to say that I am not sure which answer to mark as the answer. Yours or mine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bjornredemption, I used the following code snippet:

```
$args = array('category' => $wp_query->get_queried_object_id(), 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => array( 'post', 'attachment'),'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'inherit'));
$glossaryposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Furthermore the function have_posts() must be changed because the default one does not check for attachments.